How to change a partition's attributes using DISKPART?
After a Windows 10 crash i had to delete the recovery partition and re-create it. Then i noticed that in Disk Management it's no more marked as "Healthy (Recovery Partition)". I have another drive with backup Windows installation so i can directly compare recovery partition attributes on both drives.
Disk Management screenshot
DISKPART screenshot
In DISKPART i found a couple of differences in partition attributes. Here you can see that the partition i've re-created has attributes
Required: No
Attrib  : 0000000000000000

while the untouched recovery partition on the backup drive has the following attributes:
Required: Yes
Attrib  : 0X8000000000000001

So my question is how can i change those partition attributes? Spent a day digging in the net with no result...
P.S. Both drives are GPT ones with Windows 10 Pro 22H2 installed.

You don't change the attributes on those partitions. You delete them, shrink a partition, and create a new WinRE partition.  The reason you should do that instead of trying to use what you have, is that your WinRE isn't the correct size, which means it cannot be updated..  I would be willing to bet that you have been unable to install KB5034441 if your WinRE partition is only 522MB.

You're wrong. The Windows Recovery partitition is a normal NTFS partition. It should be ideally located on your system drive, just after the normal Windows partition, because the installer can shrink that Windows partition to leave space after for the recovery partition. You can shrink the Windows partition yourself to increase the size of the recovery partition (e.g. with DiskGenius).
The recovery is ~530MB but its size grows a bit over versions and must have at least 15MB free. You can allocate 700MB once to avoid the Win installer adding new parts.

Another reason why you would want a larger recovery partition is to put there some additional tools (such as DiskGenius, or some antimalwares, or some other backup/recovery tool, or system maintenance tools, that can run in the WinPE boot environment used by the Windows installer and recovery)

Using DISKPART:

Either:

LIST VOL to list mountable volumes then SEL VOL n to select the volume (along with its partition); or
LIST DISK to list available disks then SEL DISK n to select the disk; then SEL PART n to select the partition (along with its volume): this works on partitions without a mountable volume (not containing a supported filesystem, not your case here because the file system of your Recovery partition is NTFS and supported as a valid volume, as long as it is effectively formatted as NTFS, and not just allocated/created as a blank primary partition, and its boot sector contains valid description of the NTFS volume basic properties and properly locates the necessary metafiles, including the volume allocation bitmap for clusters, the $Mft file and its own allocation bitmap for entries, the $MftMirr file mirroring the 16 first records of the main MFT, the root folder with its index files, other special files like $UpCase, $AttrDef, $LogFile, $Secure and $BadClus, and the directory entry for the bootsector and the special $Extend directory containing other metafiles for optional advanced NTFS features like TxF transactions, or ReFS extensions);


then GPT ATTRIBUTES=0x8000000000000001. You can see and confirm these GPT partition attributes with DETAIL PART.

